# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая после оборота "В случае утверждения данного требования"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обстоятельственные обороты «в случае + существительное» **могут** выделяться знаками препинания (запятыми), если они ***находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения, находятся между подлежащим и сказуемым, содержат объяснение того, о чём говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно. Однако окончательное решение о постановке запятых или их отсутствии принимает автор высказывания.***

****В случае ослушания*** музыкантов садили на гауптвахту, как простых солдат. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Верный раб. Иван Павлыч Вологжанин неутомимо начал разъезжать по всем знакомым и собирать полезные сведения о житье-бытье крутогорских обывателей, дабы, ***в случае надобности,*** преподнесть этот букет господину ревизору и чрез то заявить свою деятельность и преданность. М. Салтыков-Щедрин, Приезд ревизора. И тогда, догадавшись, что я-то ведь тоже человек, я пустился в поиски самого себя, справедливо полагая, что ***в*** ***случае неудачи*** потеря для всех небольшая, а ***в случае удачи*** это находка для многих. М. Анчаров, Сода-солнце.*

Примеры из "Словаря-справочника по пунктуации". — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010

***В Вашем случае запятую можно не ставить, так как оборот стоит, как я поняла, в начале предложения. Интонация тоже не категоричная. Впрочем, Вам решать.***

Answer (score 1):

Подразумевается условие - запятая нужна.